# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre de variables por posición y no por nombre con dplyr en R?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, funciones

Antes que cualquier cosa, quiero comentar que realicé una búsqueda exhaustiva antes de realizar mi pregunta sin obtener resultados satisfactorios.
Los nombres de la base de datos que quiero emplear son bastante largos y confusos y, por tanto, quiero cambiar su nombre pero utilizando su posición.
Algunos de los nombres de variables son:

```
 [1] "Fecha"                                                                                    
 [2] "Delegación"                                                                               
 [3] "Clave.INEGI.AGEE"                                                                         
 [4] "Código.Penal.Federal..CPF._Delitos.contra.la.salud_.Producción"                           
 [5] "Código.Penal.Federal..CPF._Delitos.contra.la.salud_Transporte"                            
 [6] "Código.Penal.Federal..CPF._Delitos.contra.la.salud_Tráfico"                               
 [7] "Código.Penal.Federal..CPF._Delitos.contra.la.salud_Comercio"                              
 [8] "Código.Penal.Federal..CPF._Delitos.contra.la.salud_Suministro"                            
 [9] "Código.Penal.Federal..CPF._Delitos.contra.la.salud_Posesión"                              
[10] "Código.Penal.Federal..CPF._Delitos.contra.la.salud_Otros"
```

Es fácil cambiar el nombre con rename usando:

```
rename(nuevo_nombre = viejo_nombre)
```

cuando se trata de nombres no tan largos. No obstante, no es el caso. 
Ahora bien, encontré soluciones como:

```
rename(!!produccion := names[4], !!transporte:= names[5],
!!trafico :=names[6], !!comercio:= names[7], !!suministro := names[8],
!!posesion := names[9], !!otros:= names[10])

Error in quos(...) : objeto 'produccion' no encontrado
```

o:

```
rename("produccion" = names[4], "transporte"= names[5],
"trafico" =names[6], "comercio"= names[7], "suministro" = names[8],
"posesion" = names[9], "otros"= names[10])

Error: Expressions are currently not supported in `rename()`
```

La segunda significa obviamente que el formato era válido en alguna versión anterior de dplyr pero no ahora. Mi pregunta es: ¿Ya no es posible cambiar el nombre de una variable por posición usando `rename` de `dplyr`? ¿Qué alternativas existen, en particular si quiero utilizar el operador `%>%` dado que facilita una lectura precisa de cómo se va manipulando la base de datos?

Agradezco cualquier comentario y orientación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo con frecuencia el mismo problema analizando bases de datos de encuestas: los nombres de variables son la pregunta, así que son largos, con espacios en el medio y caracteres especiales. Espantoso estar repitiéndolos todo el tiempo, por más autocompletado que tenga RStudio.

Va una respuesta un tanto larga, ojalá sirva para tu caso y para que compartamos estrategias para atender este problema.

Como mencionas `dplyr::rename()` no funciona con números de índice. Esto tiene que ver en parte con la filosofía de Wickham, que viene más del manejo de bases de datos relacionales en los que los números de índice no tienen cabida y también con cuestiones de la evaluación no estándar que usa el `tidyverse`. Esas funciones son fáciles de usar: no es necesario usar comillas para las cadenas y no es necesarios crear explícitamente vectores usando `c()` para hacer llamadas múltiples, pero por eso mismo tienen problemas para mezclar de número y cadenas en los argumentos de una función. Por eso en el `tidyverse` siempre se usan nombres de columna y casi nunca números de índice. `select()` es una excepción.

## Preámbulo

Primero un comentario más general: no me parece buena práctica usar los número de índice para hacer el subsetting de un `data.frame` o manipulaciones como el cambio de nombre. ¿Por qué? Porque eso funciona si tu estructura de datos es estable y los números de índice y nombres coinciden siempre. Pero si estás usando el operador `%>%` estás tratando a tu estructura de datos de manera dinámica (dentro de la cadena de funciones). Entonces corrés el riesgo de que al eliminar una variable las siguientes estén ubicadas un número menos y si aplicás un cambio basado en números de índice el resultado no va a ser el que estás buscando. Soy un poco exagerado con esto, aunque haya contextos en los que no es tan riesgoso prefiero no usar nunca lo que es potencialmente una mala práctica, para "olvidarme" de como se hace y no recurrir a ese "atajo" en otro contexto en el que sí es riesgoso.

## Opción preferida: un diccionario y usar nombres cortos.

La alternativa que uso es generar un conjunto de nombre cortos para las columnas de mi base de datos, así cuando las estoy manipulando las llamo por nombre corto. Para eso hago -o importo si está disponible en la fuente de la que obtengo los datos- un `diccionario` de variables. Un simple `data.frame` con al menos dos columnas, `Variable` y `Etiqueta`. `Variable` es el nombre corto, que uso para referirme a esa columna durante la manipulación de datos, `etiqueta` un nombre largo y muy descriptivo que uso en gráfico o tablas.

Esa si querés la podés armar el Excel o similar, exportarla a .csv e importarla en la sesión de R que necesites o generarla directamente en R. Por convención en el entorno de R *siempre* la llamo `diccionario`.

En la práctica uso al diccionario junto con a dos simples funciones ad hoc: `nombrar_largo()` y `nombrar_corto()`. La primera se encarga de hacer el match y cambio de nombres de cortos a largos, la segundo lo inverso. Por como están escritas no fallan cuando no hay coincidencia en el número de columnas (es decir, podrías usarlas después de un `select()`) y tampoco fallan si hay columnas nuevas (las deja sin cambios), pero **requieren que el orden de los nombres de columnas en `x` y el de las filas en el `df` sea igual**.

Lo que te permiten es hacer todo el procesamiento y manipulación con los nombres cortos y cuando querés, por ejemplo, generar un gráfico en el que estén los nombres largos, simplemente agregás `nombrar_largo() %>%` en el lugar adecuado de tu cadena de funciones y listo.

Va un ejemplo práctico, de una base con la que estoy trabajado y que podés descargar acá: http://portalanterior.ine.mx/archivos2/s/DECEYEC/EducacionCivica/Base_datos_Informe_Pais.xlsx

```
# El data.frame que analizo se llama basecalidad y la tabla de equivalencias entre variables y etiquetas se llama diccionario. 


diccionario %>% slice(10:15)  #Una parte del diccionario, para entender la estructura.

# A tibble: 6 x 2
Variable                                                                                                                                                                                            Etiqueta
<chr>                                                                                                                                                                                               <chr>
  1       p2          P2. En su opinión, si una persona mata a alguien y las autoridades no hacen nada, ¿los miembros de la comunidad tienen derecho o no tienen derecho de hacer justica con sus propias manos?
  2       p3 P3. Tomando en cuenta lo que sucede en su comunidad, ¿está muy de acuerdo, algo de acuerdo, algo en desacuerdo o muy en desacuerdo  con la frase La policía hace de mi colonia un lugar más seguro?
  3       p4                                             P4. En lo relativo al cumplimiento de las leyes vigentes en su estado y en el país, ¿cuál de las siguientes frases se acerca más a lo que usted piensa?
  4       p5                           P5.  En su opinión, qué es más importante: ¿Qué las autoridades respeten los derechos humanos o que las autoridades capturen a personas acusadas de cometer algún delito?
  5       p6                                                                                                                                     P6.  ¿Cuál de las siguientes situaciones considera que es peor?
  6     p7_1                                               P7. Por favor dígame,  si en los últimos doce meses usted  Ha cambiado los lugares a donde va de compras  por temor a ser víctima de la delincuencia.


nombrar_largo <- function(x){
  nombres <- diccionario [diccionario$Variable %in% colnames(x),"Etiqueta"]$Etiqueta
  colnames(x) <- nombres
  return(x)
}

nombrar_corto <- function(x){
  nombres <- diccionario [diccionario$Etiqueta %in% colnames(x), "Variable"]$Variable
  colnames(x) <- nombres
  return(x)
}

# Uso

basecalidad %>% 
  nombrar_largo() %>%      #Regresa la misma base con nombres largos. 
  select(-proy, -edo) %>%  #Quito dos columnas.
  nombrar_corto()          #Sigue funcionando.
```

Estas funciones son mejorables, ya que requieren algunos nombres fijos: diccionario, Etiqueta, Variable y además tienen el problema del orden. Sin embargo como funcionan no me he puesto a meterles mano. Además son un poco lentas para bases muy anchas, porque `%in%` es bastante perezoso. Pero como funcionan para lo que las necesito no me he puesto a mejorarlas.

## Método alternativo con la función `nombrar()`

Si es demasiado trabajo hacer el diccionario y preferís una solución más rápida (en el corto plazo) podés usar una variación de la función `setNames()`, a la que llamé `nombrar()`. `setNames()` recibe dos argumentos, un `data.frame` y un vector de nombres, el problema es que no maneja bien los números de índice. Por eso la modifiqué un poco para que reciba un tercer argumento: un vector numérico con los índices. También cambié el orden de los argumentos: el primero es el `data.frame`, así que usando `%>%` lo podés dejar vacío, el segundo un vector numérico con los índices y el tercero un vector de caracteres con los nombres que te plazcan para las variables seleccionadas por número.

```
nombrar <- function (object = nm, index, nm) 
{
  names(object)[index] <- nm
  object
}
# Uso:

basecalidad %>% 
  nombrar(c(1, 5, 6), c("Nombre de la uno", "Nombre de la cinco", "Nombre de la seis"))
```

Eso sí, para cada uso tenés que asegurarte de que el el vector de índices y el de nombre tengan el mismo largo y coincidan por ubicación. Pero al tener como input a un `data.frame` y regresar la misma estructura como output podés usarla con el operador `%>%`.

## Opción 3: usar un `gsub()` ad hoc

A veces el nombre corto que buscamos está en los nombres largos e incómodos y sólo es cuestión de quitar lo que sobra con una expresión regular o directamente una cadena. Se puede usar `gsub()` sobre el vector `names()` de tu base de datos, en este caso uso setNames() para envolver el proceso en una funcion. En tu caso sería algo así como:

```
df %>%
   setNames(gsub("Código.Penal.Federal..CPF._Delitos.contra.la.salud_", "", .))
#No arme la estructura de datos y no lo pude probar. Un `dput(head(datos))`  ayudaría.
```

Saludos!

Comment: Justo comenzaba a pensar cómo aplicar la idea detrás  de names[indices] <- c(nuevos nombres) a través de una función ad hoc y me encuentro con tu respuesta. Gracias por tu tiempo, me daré la oportunidad de leer todo con mucha calma. Saludos!

Comment: Dejé una respuesta propia. Quizás pueda ser de tu interés. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Has intentado usar las otra familias de funciones asociadas a `rename`, como lo son `rename_at` o `rename_all`, las cuales pueden recibir una funcion (como las que @mpaladino recomendó)?

El ejemplo es más descriptivo:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- head(iris, 3)
data
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa

data %>% rename_at(2, function(x) "2da varaible")
#>   Sepal.Length 2da varaible Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1          3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9          3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7          3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa


antiguos <- names(data)
antiguos
#> [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
#> [5] "Species"

nuevos <- str_replace_all(str_to_lower(names(data)), "\\.", "_")
nuevos <- str_c(nuevos, stringi::stri_rand_strings(length(nuevos), 2), sep = "_")
nuevos
#> [1] "sepal_length_nP" "sepal_width_Ws"  "petal_length_r4" "petal_width_pY" 
#> [5] "species_4O"

data %>% rename_all(function(x) nuevos[which(antiguos %in% x)])
#>   sepal_length_nP sepal_width_Ws petal_length_r4 petal_width_pY species_4O
#> 1             5.1            3.5             1.4            0.2     setosa
#> 2             4.9            3.0             1.4            0.2     setosa
#> 3             4.7            3.2             1.3            0.2     setosa


data %>% rename_all(str_to_upper)
#>   SEPAL.LENGTH SEPAL.WIDTH PETAL.LENGTH PETAL.WIDTH SPECIES
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Muy buena alternativa. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Revisando algunos viejos apuntes de R, di con una respuesta que puede servir para quienes den una lectura a esta publicación. La solución está en emplear el operador `%>%` y funciones base R.

Utilizaré la base mtcars para ejemplificar.

Primero, veamos los nombres de las variables de la base de datos.

```
head(mtcars, 3)
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Supongamos que me interesa seleccionar las variables mpg, cyl y hp (Recordemos que la naturaleza del problema es cambiar nombres para variables con nombres no muy sencillos, pero de cualquier forma funciona igual)

```
library(dplyr)

head(mtcars) %>%
+   subset(select=c(1:2,4)) %>% 
+   setNames(c("millas","cilindros", "caballos")) 
                  millas cilindros caballos
Mazda RX4           21.0         6      110
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0         6      110
Datsun 710          22.8         4       93
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4         6      110
Hornet Sportabout   18.7         8      175
Valiant             18.1         6      105
```

Como se aprecia, el resultado es el deseado. El quid de todo esto es usar `subset` y `setNames`que son funciones de código base R.  Una solución alternativa y también bastante efectiva.

Espero que a alguien le sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

Con la función `colnames()` es muy fácil realizar lo que decís, por ejemplo si la primer columna de mi dataset quiero que se llame "Fecha" la instrucción es `colnames(data)[1]="Fecha"` donde el 1 señala que es la primer columna a la cual se le desea cambiar nombre